# Proof of the phase of the Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

From [wikipdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform):

> The Fourier transform of a function of time is itself a complex-valued
>   function of frequency, whose absolute value represents the amount of
>   that frequency present in the original function, and whose complex
>   argument is the phase offset of the basic sinusoid in that frequency.

Can anyone provide a proof of this?

**EDIT**

Allen suggested I should start by finding $\mathcal{F}[\sin(a(x-b))]$

Using the fact that

$$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

I get

$$\mathcal{F}[\sin(a(x-b))] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(a(x-b) -2\pi xz) dx$$

if I haven't made a mistake.

**EDIT**

I'll try to restate what wikipedia is saying in mathematical terms.

> The Fourier transform of a function of time is itself a complex-valued
>   function of frequency

$ \mathcal{F}[f(x)] = z(t) = r(t) e^{i \theta (t)}$

For $z \in \mathbb{C}$

> whose absolute value represents the amount of that frequency present
>   in the original function

Amount of frequency present:

$ |z(t)| = r(t)$

> and whose complex argument is the phase offset

Phase Offset:

$e^{i\theta(t)}$

Comment: If only there was a citation

Comment: Try computing the Fourier transform of $f(x) = sin(a(x-b))$.

Comment: @AllenMorris Do I use the property $sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$   to get the result?

Comment: Which definition of the Fourier transform are you using? Also, just do the Fourier transform and notice that the time component will be integrated out, leaving a function of frequency.

Comment: @Mattos $\mathcal{F}(f(x)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i2\pi xz} dx$ What other definition could the wiki article be refering to? It's not DCT. I gathered from the article that the Fourier Transform gives a complex result. ie: one of the form $re^{i\theta}$ . It says the absolute value ($r$) is the frequency, and the 'complex argument' (I presume $e^{i\theta}$) is the phase offset.

Comment: It could be referring to either $$\mathcal{F}(f(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{i \omega x} dx$$ where the inverse transform is also scaled by $1/\sqrt{2 \pi}$, or $$\mathcal{F}(f(x)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{i \omega x} dx$$ where the inverse transform is scaled by $1/2\pi$, for starters. I don't know what you mean by 'it's not the DCT'. No one said anything about the DCT.

Comment: @Mattos oh ... I was not aware there was more than one Fourier Transform definition. In any case, a scalar factor out the from won't make too much difference to the phase offset. Wait ... shouldn't there be a negative sign in the exponent? Is that the inverse Fourier Transform?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the negative exponent goes. It can be in the forward transform or the inverse transform. As long as one is $+$ and one is $-$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY